# convert the list of sequence list to one hot

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have below example: I wish to convert each list of sequences list to one hot encoder.

For example I have a list of 2 sentences. I first convert these sentences to sequences list.

then for each list of sequences list, I then convert the sequence to one hot based on each word.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from itertools import chain
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

a = ['hi', 'oh thanks i m fine this is an evening in my timezone']
a_tokens = [word_tokenize(word) for word in a]
tokens_dict = {word:i for i, word in enumerate(set(chain.from_iterable(a_tokens)))}
tokens_sequence = [[tokens_dict[word_t] for word_t in word] for word in a_tokens]
```

current output:

```
[[4], [2, 5, 3, 1, 8, 7, 9, 0, 12, 10, 11, 6]]
```

expected output:

```
[[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]],
 [[-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-],
  [-12 0s but 1 for the repsective word-]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_categorical of keras.utils.np_utils to get one_hot_vectors of your labels as follows:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from itertools import chain
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

a = ['hi', 'oh thanks i m fine this is an evening in my timezone']
a_tokens = [word_tokenize(word) for word in a]
tokens_dict = {word:i for i, word in enumerate(set(chain.from_iterable(a_tokens)))}
tokens_sequence = [[tokens_dict[word_t] for word_t in word] for word in a_tokens]

labels=np.array(tokens_sequence)

max_label=max([max(l) for l in labels]) # get maximum value in labels= the label of the word with highest label; here is 12

one_hot_labels=[]
for label in labels: 
    label.append(max_label) # add the label of the word with highest label
    one_hot=to_categorical(label,dtype=np.int32)   #get one-hot-labels  
    one_hot_labels.append( one_hot[:-1]) # remove one-hot of the word with highest label and add reaming into the list 
    
one_hot_labels=np.array(one_hot_labels)
print(one_hot_labels)
```

Hope this helps.